# Response.Redirect error on mobile devices

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mobile

On my main login screen, i am checking to see if the browser is a mobile browser.  If the browser is a mobile browser i redirect the user to the mobile website login screen.  This works fine on my Android device but not on my Iphone.  I went and tried putting in Response.End() after my redirects but that caused my Android device to start getting the error message.  The message i am getting on both devices is that there are to many server redirects.  Any Hints?

Edit:

```
if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] != null && (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true" 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("MIDP") || Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("CLDC") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("iphone") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("avant") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("nokia") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("pda") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("moto") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("windows ce") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("hand") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("mobi") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("HTC") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("sony") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("panasonic") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("blackberry") 
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("240x320") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("voda"))
            || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("android") || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad")) 
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Login.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the code you use to determine that you are encountering a mobile browser? Also, is there any point on your mobile login page that the mobile page also performs the same check and redirects, causing a loop?

Comment: I know you're not asking this, but throwing it out there. You might want to check out the http://51degrees.codeplex.com/ Mobile Device Detection and Redirection. It does all the work above for you and gives you more specific device details.

Comment: added my code above, it's nothing special.

Comment: What’s that tilde doing in front of your URL?

Comment: Takes me back to the root of the directory.

Comment: @lthibodeaux I think you might be onto the right idea.  Do the login pages inherit from each other?  Is it possible this code is also run on the mobile login page?

Answer (score 0):

Check event viewer logs on the server.  Might also want to try doing Response.Redirect(urlString, false);

Response.Redirect(urlString); does a Response.End() inside and can cause issues with threads aborting.  This is expected and not a big deal but it will throw as an exception.

Comment: I've ran into that problem before with it causing threads to abort, this is a different problem though.  And i still even tried that and it did the same thing.